# boost regex match non-whitespace and angle brackets

Tags: regex, boost

I may be asking a duplicate question, but I've spent a couple of hours googling this to no avail!

I'm trying to extract a string from some SIP URLs parsed by a program I'm working on. Here's an excerpt of the code. I'm passing in `sipUrl`, and have all the right includes etc:

```
static const boost::regex sipRegExp ("(sip:\\S+?@(?=\\S)[^>]+);");
boost::cmatch result;
boost::match_results<string::const_iterator> results;
boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::format_perl;
string newSipUrl;
cout << sipUrl << endl;

bool toggle = boost::regex_search(sipUrl, result, sipRegExp, flags);
if (toggle) {
    cout << result[1].str() << endl;
    newSipUrl = result[1].str();
}

cout << "new url: " << newSipUrl << endl;
```

I'm basically trying to extract the `sip:user@IP` from strings like `"\"alex@192.168.1.2\"<sip:alex@192.168.1.2>;tag=fe310852"` or `"\"bob\"<sip:bob@foo.com>;"`, however, I can't get it to match! It worked fine when I wasn't using lookahead to try and remove the last angle bracket, but ever since then it fails to match.

Posting this just before running out of the door, so it may need more info. If anyone can spot something glaringly obvious, then that'd be a great help! And please feel free to point me at links that I might have missed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `>` before the semicolon:

```
"(sip:\\S+?@(?=\\S)[^>]+)>;"
```

Although actually you probably don't need the semicolon at all. Something like Scott's answer should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something simpler such as regex against:

```
`sip:[a-zA-Z]*@[0-9a-zA-Z.]*`
```

works on terminal but haven't tried it through boost yet. If you start of with something simple then add bit by bit to make it more specific then it will be easier to track which part of the regex isn't working.

Comment: The character classes could do with some more characters. I'd say `"sip:[-_0-9a-zA-Z]*@[-_0-9a-zA-Z.]*"` at least. Or maybe even just `"sip:\\S*@[^\\s>]*"`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with a modification of @David Knipe's comment - the winning regex was:

```
sip:\\S+@[^\\s>;]+
```

Which matches with or without angle brackets, up to the colon. Both answers provided did work, but being able to remove the lookahead was quite nice. I also went with the `+` modifiers to make some effort to find a valid URI and not a blank one.

Thanks for the help!